# How to create random pixel art pattern in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, gradient, pixel-art

I just need to do the same process that was done in
[this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87015/pixel-art-randomness),
but in GIMP.

I can add noise to the image in gimp, but I don't know which sliders should I move to get the wanted effect.

Comment: Welcome on GD.Se, Salem. Can you please tell us something more about your efforts? Have you tried to replicate in GIMP the steps described in the first answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an easier way

1. Create a new image with as many pixels as you need.
2. Choose a new foreground colour, i.e. a green colour for the grass, and fill the canvas with it using *Edit  > Fill with FG colour*
3. Do *Filters > Noise > HSV Noise*, and move the Value slider until you get the effect you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use a color-indexed image, a different solution is to use the `Dissolve` move that replaces random pixels with another color. Either:

Using another layer:

- Add a layer, fill with a color from the color palette
- Set layer to `Dissolve` mode
- Reduce the layer opacity to  obtain the adequate color mix

Using the paint tool directly:

- Set the FG color from  the color palette
- Set the paint tool (brush/bucket) to `Dissolve` mode
- Reduce the tool opacity
- Paint

Comment: thank you! another great solution !