# Can I make noise on one specific color with gimp

Tags: gimp, texture, pixel

So im creating a texture pack for minecraft and am curently making a texture for a creeper.

I allready made a face but found it a bit boring I would like to see the green color have some darker/lighter green noise.

Is it possible or do I have to delete my face and randomize the green there?

Below are 2 pictures the first is what I have and the second is what I want.
(any feedback on the face it self are welcome aswell since im not very good in making a scary 40*40 pixel face)

[image: What ive made]

[image: What I want]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create random pixel art pattern in GIMP?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150405/how-to-create-random-pixel-art-pattern-in-gimp)

Comment: @BillyKerr it does have some usefull info thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the image at hand, just use the [Color selection](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html) to select the green background, then apply any of the noise filters, for instance `Filters > Noise > HSV` with mostly "V" if you want dark/light pixels:

[image]

In practice, it helps to keep features on their own layers because you can easily edit each without having to do selections (for instance you can easily relocate eyes, etc, by just dragging the corresponding layer):

[image]

Note that you don't often need "holes", most features just cover up what is under (which is useful if you move the top features around)

[image]

Comment: okay thank you ill try it this way